# Pandas Python : Col[C] if value is in Col[A] and Col[B]

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas

I have a Dataframe like this :

```
    ColA             ColB                        ColC
"lorem ipsum"     ["lorem", "foo", "bar"]
"lorem ipsum"      NaN
NaN                ["lorem", "foo", "bar"]
NaN                 NaN
```

I'm trying to get this output :

```
    ColA             ColB                        ColC
"lorem ipsum"     ["lorem", "foo", "bar"]       "lorem"
```

I tried to use comprehension list like this :

```
df["C"] = [elem for elem in df["B"] if elem in df["A"] ]
```

but without success :

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` 
if I format my ColB as list and,
`ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index` 
if I use tuple

Some help would be appreciated, 
Thank You.

Edit + Edit 2 : Only one word (or None) is present in both column and I need to catch it to place it in column C.
I also forgot to mention that ColA and ColB could have NaN as value.

Comment: Do you want just **one** word which intersects (and, if so, what do you want to do if there are multiple)? Or do you want a list of words?

Comment: Only one word is present in both column, I'll edit my question to be more explicit

Comment: First check if that ColB is String or list ?

Answer (score 2):

Use custom function with `try+except` and pass DataFrame by [`pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['lorem ipsum','lorem ipsum',np.nan, np.nan],
                   'B':[["lorem", "foo", "bar"], np.nan, ["lorem", "foo", "bar"], np.nan]})
print (df)
             A                  B
0  lorem ipsum  [lorem, foo, bar]
1  lorem ipsum                NaN
2          NaN  [lorem, foo, bar]
3          NaN                NaN

def test(df):
    out = []
    for a, b in zip(df["A"], df["B"]):
        try:
            out.append(next(y for y in b if y in a))
        except Exception:
            out.append('')
    return out

df["C"] = df.pipe(test)
print (df)
             A                  B      C
0  lorem ipsum  [lorem, foo, bar]  lorem
1  lorem ipsum                NaN       
2          NaN  [lorem, foo, bar]       
3          NaN                NaN
```

Another solution working badly:

```
df = df.fillna("undefined")
df["C"] = [next((y for y in b if y in a), '') for a, b, in zip(df["A"],df["B"])]
print (df)


             A                  B  C
0  lorem ipsum      [d, foo, bar]   
1  lorem ipsum          undefined  u
2    undefined  [lorem, foo, bar]   
3    undefined          undefined  u
```

Comment: I like the idea, but IMO `map` works better than `list.append` in a loop :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define custom function and then use `map`:

```
# data adapted from @jezrael
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['lorem ipsum', 'lorem ipsum', np.nan, np.nan, 'test string'],
                   'B':[["lorem", "foo", "bar"], np.nan, ["lorem", "foo", "bar"], np.nan, ["no", "match"]]})

def tester(val1, val2):
    if (val1 != val1) or (val2 != val2):
        return ''
    return next((x for x in val2 if x in val1), '')

df['C'] = list(map(tester, df['A'], df['B']))
```

The default parameter of `''` ensures you have an empty string where there is no match. We also take advantage of the fact `np.nan != np.nan`.

Result:

```
print(df)

             A                  B      C
0  lorem ipsum  [lorem, foo, bar]  lorem
1  lorem ipsum                NaN       
2          NaN  [lorem, foo, bar]       
3          NaN                NaN       
4  test string        [no, match]
```

Comment: Check comment under my answer.

Comment: I still got the TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
I forgot to mention that some element of ColA or ColB could be NaN, I added it to my Question.

Comment: It is nice I can learn something new from you, thank you! plus1

Answer (score 0):

The previous solution worked like a charm after I replaced every NaN with fillna.

```
df = df.fillna("undefined")
df["C"] = [next((y for y in b if y in a), '') for a, b, in zip(df["A"],df["B"])]
```

Thank You

Comment: I test your sample data and it working badly with this solution, are you sure it working nice?

Comment: Check my answer with output of sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Without try and except solution and it works for one word!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA':['lorem ipsum','lorem ipsum',None,None],
                   'colB':[["lorem", "foo", "bar"],None,["lorem", "foo", "bar"],None]})

df.loc[:,'colC'] = df.apply(lambda x: ''.join([w for w in x.colA.split() \
                             if w in x.colB]) if all(x) else '',axis=1 )

    colA    colB    colC
0   lorem ipsum [lorem, foo, bar]   lorem
1   lorem ipsum None    None
2   None    [lorem, foo, bar]   None
3   NaN None    None
```

Comment: also expected output is empty string, not None

Comment: Thanks for helping me to learn. could you mention the example, where it fails.

Comment: sure, `[lorem ipsum, foo, bar]`

Comment: So only mention in answer solution for one word test and it is OK ;)